# Passing data between routes using different components in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a very small React app with 3 routes, each route using a different component, like so:

```
const App = () => (
    <IntlProvider locale ={locale} messages={lang}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="h-100">
                <Route path="/" component={Register} exact={true} />
                <Route path="/mfa" component={MFA} />
                <Route path="/verify" component={Verify} />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </IntlProvider>
);
```

On the first route, I'm collecting some data that I need to pass over the second and third route/component. A -> B and A -> C, since the 3 routes are not correlative.

Since the components are not parent/child, I don't seem to find a clean way of passing this data.

This data is currently stored as state, like so:

```
export default class Register extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
    authCode: "",
    email: "",
    country: "",
    countryCode: "",
    onlyPhone: "",
  };

  ...

};
```

Any tips on how to approach this the *React way*?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Redux for this
https://react-redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily navigate between your routes using history and then append your collected data as a state to the history.

Functional component example:

```js
const App = () => {
    const data = {
        // your collected data here
    }

    const history = useHistory()

    const redirect = () => {
        history.push({
            pathname: `/yourroute`,
            state: {
                data: data
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        // your jsx
    )
}
```

afterwards you can access it under the next route like

```
const YourNextRouteComponent = () => {
    const history = useHistory()

    // or send it directly to the state
    const [data, setData] = useState(history.location.state.data)

    useEffect((() => {
        console.log(history.location.state.data)
    }, [])
}
```

**EDIT:**

As the others mentioned you could handle this with Context or Redux too but when your data is fetched/created in Component A and the next route (Component B) isn't a direct child of A you can't access it directly, so in this case you had to pass it up to a shared parent component. And with using redux you would make it accessibly through the whole app, which could overload your global from time to time. With history state you have a nice and clean connection between the two routes/components only.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible through Redux, LocalStorage, React Context.
Decide for yourself what is best for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between multiple components that don't have relationships, you need to use a state manager like Redux. In your case, I advise you to use [Context of React.JS](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

As your components do not have relationships, you must place your `Provider` at the root in the `index.js` file:

```js
//...
<YourContext.Provider value={yourData}>
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
</YourContext.Provider>
```